# basic server security

Tags: security, autohotkey

I am playing with a simple webserver in autohotkey: [sparrow](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36047).  It is immune to path traversal attacks.  As long as I don't run any unsanitized code from the client side, is there any other basic attack to watch out for, like the path traversal attack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit awkward.  Not sanitizing user input is what causes vulnerabilities like Directory Traversal.  The whole point is that your server is accepting the most malformed tainted data that a user could produce and the application is expected to make it safe.

There is something called a web application firewall which can block many different types of attacks before they reach the web application.  A more secure setup than Sparrow would be Apache with [Mod_Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/).  Mod_secuirty prevents hundreds of different types of attacks against web applications including Directory Traversal and the majority of the  [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007) .   The OWASP top 10 is a great resource I highly recommend it.